# Are Vardo and Varda two different people?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, languages

As the Fellowship was parting from Lórien, Lady Galadriel sings a song in Elven. The song talks about Elbereth.

The poem goes like this:

> Ai! laurië lantar lassi súrinen,
> yéni únótimë ve rámar aldaron!
> Yéni ve lintë yuldar avánier
> mi oromardi lisse-miruvóreva
> Andúnë pella, **Vardo** tellumar
> nu luini yassen tintilar i eleni
> ómaryo airetári-lírinen.
>
> Sí man i yulma nin enquantuva?
>
> An sí Tintallë **Varda** Oiolossëo
> ve fanyar máryat Elentári ortanë,
> ar ilyë tier undulávë lumbulë;
> ar sindanóriello caita mornië
> i falmalinnar imbë met, ar hísië
> untúpa Calaciryo míri oialë.
> Sí vanwa ná, Rómello vanwa, Valimar!

As you can see there is a Vardo and a Varda. When Frodo translated it he only spoke of Varda.
Is it a typing mistake or are Vardo and Varda two different people? Or maybe it's some Elven grammatical rule?

Answer (score 23):

**"Varda" and "Vardo" refer to the same person: the Vala<sup>1</sup> Varda**.

The difference between the two words is a grammatical rule; it's essentially the difference between "Varda" and "Varda's" (as in "belonging to Varda").

I can't find a reference from Tolkien himself at the moment (someone who has *History of Middle-earth* V may be able to provide a quote from the discussion of Quenya phonology in that volume), but [this translation by *Ardalambion*](https://folk.uib.no/hnohf/namarie.htm)<sup>2</sup> translates the line (emphasis theirs):

> *Vardo tellumar nu luini yassen tintilar i eleni ómaryo airetári-lírinen*
> "under Varda's blue vaults wherein the stars tremble in the voice of her song, holy and queenly": **Vardo** is the genitive of Varda

[In comments, Sean Duggan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84570/are-vardo-and-varda-two-different-people/84571?noredirect=1#comment183677_84571) points me to a [Wikibook on Neo-Quenyan morphology](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Neo-Quenya/Genitive#Singular) which describes the genitive rules for different suffixes. The relevant rule is (emphasis theirs):

> In words on **-a** this final letter is replaced by **-o**:
>
> **máma** "sheep" → **mámo**

[Genitive case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case), if you're not a grammar nerd, is the possessive form of a noun.

**Varda** and **Elbereth** are both names for one of the Queens of the Valar, though Varda is her "proper" name and Elbereth is more of an epithet, identified in *The Silmarillion*:

> With Manwë dwells Varda, Lady of the Stars, who knows all the regions of Eä. Too great is her beauty to be declared in the words of Men or of Elves; for the light of Ilúvatar lives still in her face. In light is her power and her joy. *[...]* Of all the Great Ones who dwell in this world the Elves hold Varda most in reverence and love. Elbereth they name her, and they call upon her name out of the shadows of Middle-earth, and uplift it in song at the rising of the stars.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Silmarillion*, *Valaquenta*, "Of the Valar"</sub></sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Singular form of "Valar." At this point you may be thinking to yourself "that seems awfully grammatically pedantic." Yeah, it's going to be that kind of answer

<sup>2</sup> *Ardalambion* is a fansite maintained by [Helge Kåre Fauskanger](https://folk.uib.no/hnohf/whoami.htm), a Norwegian philologist<sup>3</sup> and Tolkien enthusiast. His project is one of the most comprehensive sources on Tolkien's constructed languages

<sup>3</sup> Person who studies the historical development of languages. Tolkien was also one, you won't be surprised to learn

Comment: Maybe http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Neo-Quenya/Genitive#Formation?

Comment: @SeanDuggan I've added it, although I'd really like to add a quote from Tolkien. Couldn't find anything in Letters, and I don't have *HoME* V. I'll check the Appendices when I get home tonight, but I don't have a lot of confidence

Comment: According to a non-canon source (_La lengua de los Elfos - ISBN 84-450-7397-4_), there are two genitive cases in Quenya, *Vardo* being a partitive-derivative genitive (indicating a source or origin), while e.g: *lisse-miruvóreva* is a possessive-adjectival genitive.

Comment: According to that book, a letter from Tolkien to Dick Plotz has the full declinations for _kirya_ and _lasse_, and gives as a reference _Basic Quenya - Nancy Martsch, Beyond Bree_.

Comment: @ninjalj If so, that letter isn't included in Tolkien's *Letters*; the only letter to Dick Plotz contains a brief discussion of the etymology of Númenor, but nothing else linguistic in nature

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's a Quenya grammatical feature. The -o ending here is how Quenyan language shows posession. "Vardo tellumar" translates as "vaults of Varda" or "Varda's vaults."

There's another example of this in the same song:

> untúpa Calaciryo míri oialë

"Calaciryo míri" means "the treasure (jewels) of Calacirya."